# Viewing entire Python script of process ( input settings and environment settings) in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geoprocessing, environment-variable, results

When you "copy as python snippet" from the results of a process, the script contains all of the input settings but does not contain the environment settings. Why is this?

Is it possible to also view the code of the environment settings of a process that you run? meaning the entire script of the process.

Comment: No, it's not possible in ArcMap. Copying as python includes environment settings as well as input parameters in ArcGIS Pro though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complement Copy As Python Snippet in ArcMap, to save the environment settings you could use [`arcpy.SaveSettings(file_name)`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/savesettings.htm) which:

> Saves environment settings to an environment settings file (text
> stored in an Extensible Markup Language [XML] schema). See also
> [LoadSettings](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/loadsettings.htm) on how to load environment settings from an XML
> file.